# Realize Entity Framework one-to-one relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, one-to-one, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to realize a one-to-one relation in Entity Framework with Code First. I want to create an Airplane table which has a FlightPlan.

Airplane:

```
public class Airplane
{
    [Key]
    public int AirplaneId { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public AirplaneStatus AirplaneStatus { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfPassengers { get; set; }
    public int AirfieldId { get; set; }

    public virtual FlightPlan FlightPlan { get; set; }
}
```

FlightPlan:

```
public class FlightPlan
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Airplane")]
    public int AirplaneId { get; set; }
    public int AirfieldFrom { get; set; }
    public int AirfieldTo { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfPassengers { get; set; }

    public virtual Airplane Airplane { get; set; }
}
```

When i initialize these classes with Migrations the following table structure is created:

[image]

After i manage to create an Airplane with a FlightPlan, which takes some workarounds, the Airplane doesn't have a Flightplan no matter what i try.

[image]

[image]

How can i solve this?

**Edit**

For testing purposes i add a FlightPlan to every updated Airplane. After fixing this a route is created for adding a Flightplan. The code is:

```
var airplane = _context.Airplanes.Find(model.AirplaneId);
var flightplan = new FlightPlan() { AirfieldFrom = 1, AirfieldTo = 2, AmountOfPassengers = 30 };
airplane.FlightPlan = flightplan;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The solution for my problem is to force EF to include the FlightPlan when retrieving an Airplane.

Comment: did you created a flight plan and added it to the DB? Post the airplane/flight plan creation code.

Comment: Your model is correct. Show the insert code. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-one-to-one-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: by the way why do you have `AmountOfPassengers` on both - the flight and the airplane? Is the one on the airplane supposed to be capacity?

Comment: The AmountOfPassengers on the Airplane is redundant and will be removed. Thanks for the observation :)

Comment: I will post the creation of airplane/flightplan later. I will also let You people know if the answers helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to lazy loading since your `FlightPlan` is `virtual`.

```
var airplane = db.Airplanes.First(); //pull airplane from db
var passengerAmount = airplane.FlightPlan.AmountOfPassengers //attempting to use 
// FlightPlan property after pulling Airplane from db should load the FlightPlan
```

You can also force EF to include the `FlightPlan` property when pulling from the db.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
var airplane = db.Airplanes.Include(m => m.FlightPlan).First();
```

Comment: Forcing EF to include the FlightPlan propery did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Should be done in the following way:

```
public class Airplane
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual FlightPlan FlightPlan { get; private set; }

    // ... other properties
}

public class FlightPlan
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual Airplane Airplane { get; private set; }

    // ... other properties
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<FlightPlan>()
       .HasRequired(flightPlan => flightPlan.Airplane)
       .WithOptional(airplane => airplane.FlightPlan);

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Your setters of course could be `public`.

Comment: I believe his code is correct. This code will yield an error about not being able to determine the principal end of the relationship. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s07.html

Comment: I disagree, the code I have posted will work and will generate the following data tables: `Airplane: int ID`, `FlightPlan: int Id, int AirplaneId`. In the link you have posted they don't even provide the definition of the class `Person`

Comment: Unless you have some fluent code you are not showing you will get the error "Unable to determine principal end of the relation". I just tried it in EF 6.1.3.

Comment: You are right, I've just tested it too. I had to remove the FK from FlightPlan and add a little Fluent API. Now it almost looks like OP's original code, so indeed, it seems to be correct.